# Well known proofs that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z) \cong C_2 * C_3$

Tags: group-theory

I've seen one proof of $\mathrm{psl}_2(\mathbf Z) \cong C_2 * C_3$ based on the [Ping-pong lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma)

But what I'm looking for is how this result was historically obtained first.

I've checked Coxeter & Moser's "Generators and relations for discrete groups" and they (§7.2) do things that I find weird, they let the matrices act on circles in the half-plane $y>0$ which in turn they regard as lines of a hyperbolic plane, it then follows this group can be interpreted as triangle group acting on a hyperbolic triangle.

Is this indeed the 'classic' way to arrive at this result? And if so, I'd be happy with a bit of an explanation of what's going on, or a reference to a text where this is explained a bit more in detail, because I'm really not that comfortable with hyperbolic triangles.

Comment: He doesn't write it up quite the way you'd like but the core of Coxeter and Moser's argument is present in Hatcher's "Topology of numbers" book, available here: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html

Comment: Well, I've been gazing through it and it's interesting to read even though the style is a bit weird.

Comment: Here is a link to replace the one in the comment of @RyanBudney: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNpage.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the history, but if you want to understand 'what's going on' the keyword is 'orbifold'.  I recommend Peter Scott's article 'The geometries of 3-manifolds', available as a pdf on [his website](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pscott/), for an introduction to 2-dimensional orbifolds.